# Previous/next occur result, independently from compilation errors

Tags: compilation, navigation, occur

After running `M-x occur`, the commands `next-error` and `previous-error` let me navigate between hits.

I would like to be able to `M-x compile` my program and then keep browsing through the same `*Occur*` results. But if I compile then `next-error` and `previous-error` navigate the compilation errors, which makes perfect sense.

I don't want to run `M-x occur` again because I'd lose my place. What I want is to navigate occur results independently of compilation results.

How can I define `next-occur` and `previous-occur` commands that do this? (Note that this is not `occur-next` and `occur-prev`, which operate in the `*Occur*` buffer. I want to bind these to keys in the buffer that's being searched.)

Bonus: I'd prefer `grep` to be classified like `occur`, so I can also navigate grep results independently from compilation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of `occur-mode`, I found this:

```el
  (setq next-error-function 'occur-next-error))
```

This suggests `occur-next-error` is the function `next-error` calls in a "occured" buffer. And indeed, it seems that calling `occur-next-error` (with a negative arg to go backward) does work even after `M-x compile`. I have not tested this extensively, though.

So it would seem you just need to define a `occur-prev-error` command calling `occur-next-error` with arg -1 and use it along with `occur-next-error`.